# Async message or (message)? - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a question.
What is the different between the `async message` and only `(message)`.
Here is an example with the async
`client.on('message', async message => {CODE}`

And here is an example without the async `client.on('message', (message) => {CODE})`

I hope you can understand my question ;)

Comment: The parenthesis around the parameter of the arrow function can be omitted if there is exactly one parameter. `(message) =>` === `message =>`.

Answer (score 0):

`(message) => {}` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and `async message => {}` is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

The essential difference is that in an `async` function you can `await` for asynchronous code completion.

And as you can read in [mdn page for arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax):

```
// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

so

```
async message => {CODE}
// is equal to
async (message) => {CODE}
```

and

```
(message) => {}
// is equal to
message => {}
```

What's important is to be consistent in the way you use parentheses, and the best way to achieve 100% consistency in your code is to use a tool like [prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: What is better for a discordbot?

Comment: @verleuchtet both are useful. It depends what you're trying to do.